# subquery returning one row

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables in MySQL like this

First table: student

```
id    Name       roll     
1     vivek      22222    
2     abc        33333
```

Second table: fee

```
id    amount       roll 
1     3540         22222
2     28140        22222
```

i am trying to run

```
SELECT roll_no,sum(amount) as deposit 
FROM stu_profile 
join (select roll,amount,sum(amount) from fee group by roll) as fee on roll=roll_no 
WHERE 1 and roll='62032'
```

I want this output.

```
roll      deposit
22222     31680
```

but i am getting this

```
roll      deposit
22222     3540
```

Comment: SQL does not need to be on a single row, please make it readable without left/right scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result with this:

```
SELECT
    roll
  , SUM(amount) summed_amt
FROM fee
WHERE roll = '22222'
GROUP BY roll
;
```

But if you really do need both tables involved then try this:

```
SELECT
    roll_no
  , summed_amt
FROM stu_profile p
JOIN (
    SELECT
        roll
      , SUM(amount) summed_amt
    FROM fee
    GROUP BY roll
) AS fee
    ON p.roll_no = fee.roll
WHERE p.roll_no = '22222'
```

You don't need a SUM in the outer query because you reduce the inner query to just one row for each `roll` and you are filtering for just one roll as well.

---

by the way, only in MySQL can this this be a valid query:

```
select roll,amount,sum(amount) from fee group by roll
```

In standard SQL you could not group by just one column `roll` but output 2 columns (plus the aggregation). It is due to this that you got the incorrect result initially because this non-standard group by syntax that MySQL (badly) allows.

Research [only_full_group_by](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/02/12/why-i-use-only-full-group-by/)